# Discordpy index out of range message

Tags: python, discord

I want to make it so that if splitted variable gets the error list index out of range, it would await a message that says that the user didnt prove the required input. This is what I imagine it to be like: when I say test without anything else, it would await the message 'Error'

```
if message.content.startswith('test'):
     splitted = message.content.split(' ')[1]
     await message.channel.send(splitted)
```

Comment: It means that your message doesn't have a space in it so when it tries to split the string, it's returning the full string as a list. For example, if you have the string 'hello' and you split it by space, it will return ['hello'] which is only of length 1. Therefore you cannot get index 1 of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using try/except:

```
if message.content.startswith('test'):
    try:
        splitted = message.content.split(' ')[1]
        await message.channel.send(splitted)
    except IndexError:
        # Await here for your error
```